# Error en php Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statements

He leído ya unos cuantos artículos, pero no logro arreglar este error que tengo. Es la primera vez que veo este error, y no se como solucionarlo.
Entonces usando PHP y MYSQL para extraer unos datos de la base de datos (Valga la redundancia) y mostrarlos en forma de notificación. Estoy creando un sistema de notificaciones de usuarios, pero no me había dado cuenta.
El sistema de notificaciones (Que no es mas que un archivo **notifications.php** para extraer los datos y mostrarlos) funciona correctamente en la pagina de inicio, pero no en los perfiles o cualquier otra pagina. Vean.

En esta parte, las notificaciones funcionan correctamente

[image: Esta es la pagina de inicio, donde las notificaciones funcionan]

Pero en esta parte, que es el perfil del usuario, no funciona

[image: Esta es la pagina de perfil donde las notificaciones no funcionan]

Este el código PHP que estoy utilizando.

```
<?php

$notification = $conn->prepare("SELECT n.id_notification, 
                                       n.notification_user, 
                                       n.notification_send_user, 
                                       n.notification_title,
                                       n.notification_datetime,
                                       u.user_image,
                                       u.username
                                       FROM notifications n 
                                       INNER JOIN users u 
                                       ON u.ID = n.notification_send_user
                                       WHERE n.notification_user = ?");

if ($notification) {
    $notification->bind_param("i", $_SESSION["usuario_id"]);
    $notification->execute();
    $notification->store_result();
    $notification->bind_result($id_notification,
                               $notification_user,
                               $notification_send_user,
                               $notification_title,
                               $notification_datetime,
                               $user_image,
                               $username);

    while($notification->fetch()){
        $title = explode(';', $notification_title);

        echo '<li>
                <a href="'.$title[0].'" title="'.$title[1].'" class="list-lyrians__item">
                <img src="'.$user_image.'" alt="">
                <p>
                    '.$title[1].'

                    <span>'.$title[2].'</span>
                    <span class="timeago" title="'.$notification_datetime.'" style="padding-top: 2px;"></span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>';
    }

    $notification->close();
} else{
    echo "Ocurrió un error al mostrar las notificaciones" . $conn->error;
}
```

Si me pueden ayudar a arreglar este error, se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Seguramente estas haciendo alguna consulta antes de la que no has liberado los resultados o al usar **store_result()** es importante.  puedes echar un ojo a esto https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: Si era eso. Gracias jaja, era la primera vez que me pasaba, y bueno, estuve como loco. Casi 2hs leyendo, ese enlace también lo había leído y seguía sin entender. Gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema(php 5.6 y MariaDB) y lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

### SP:

```
   SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 99999999;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DB_cargas.TBL_FACTURAS_CUENTAS_SUSPENSION_PASO;

    CREATE TABLE DB_cargas.TBL_FACTURAS_CUENTAS_SUSPENSION_PASO
    SELECT 
    EMAIL_DESTINATARIO,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MAIL_EDAC ORDER BY MAIL_EDAC ASC) AS MAIL_EDAC,
    MANDANTE,
    SUSPENSION,
    -- SERBANC,
    SUM(MONTO) AS TOTAL, 
    NOMBRE,
    RUT,
    COUNT(RUT) AS N_DOCUMENTOS_VENCIDOS,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CUENTA,'; ',ESTADO_CUENTA,'; ', NRO_FACTURA, '; ', VENCIMIENTO, '; ', EMISION, '; ',MONTO SEPARATOR '; ') as DETALLETT
    FROM DB_cargas.TBL_FACTURAS_CUENTAS_SUSPENSION GROUP BY rut;


    SELECT * from DB_cargas.TBL_FACTURAS_CUENTAS_SUSPENSION_PASO;
```

---

```
<?php

$conexionEscritura = CreaNuevaConexion();

$sqlSP = "CALL MiBase.ProcedimientoAalmacenado();";
$resultado = mysql_query($sqlSP, $conexionEscritura) or die("Error: \n".mysql_error()."\n".$sqlSP);

while($registro = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
 .... /*Creacion de titulos para un archivo .csv con 'n' columnas como 'n' facturas de origen como filas*/
}

mysql_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($conexionEscritura);
unset($resultado,$conexionEscritura);

$conexionEscritura = CreaNuevaConexion();

$sql2 = "SELECT * from DB_cargas.TBL_FACTURAS_CUENTAS_SUSPENSION_PASO;";
$resultado_2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conexionEscritura) or die("Error: \n".mysql_error()."\n".$sql2);

.... /*Creación de la data para un archivo .csv*/

?>
```

Utilizando las 3 líneas el php corrio [OK]:

```
  mysql_free_result($resultado);
    mysql_close($conexionEscritura);
    unset($resultado,$conexionEscritura);
```

No funcionó con:

```
mysql_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($conexionEscritura);
```